# Why complains my code has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, looper

I created a **Looper thread** class:

```
public class MyLooperThread extends Thread{
    private Handler mHandler;

    public void init(){
         start(); //start the thread

         synchronized (this) {
            wait(5000); //wait for run()
         }
         Log.d("DEBUG","Init Done!");

         //EXCEPTION: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
         MyObject obj = new MyObject(mHandler);
   }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();

        mHandler = new Handler(){
           @Override
           public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            //Check installed app package names, NOTHING RELATED WITH UI                ...
            }
        };
        synchronized (this) {
            notify(); 
        }
        Looper.loop();

     }//end of run()
}
```

In my **Activity**, I call above `MyLooperThread` 's `init()` method in `onCreate()`. Besides, I have a `ToggleButton` element, when `ToggleButton` is checked, I call `MyLooperThread`'s `init()` method too.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener{
   …
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      …
      myToggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
      myToggleButton.setChecked(true);//checked by default

      MyLooperThread myLooper = new MyLooperThread();
      myLooper.init();

   }

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button, boolean isChecked) {
    if(isChecked){
          MyLooperThread myLooper = new MyLooperThread();
          myLooper.init();
      }else{
          ...
      }
    }
}
```

When launch my app, it is fine. My toggle button is shown as checked by default. When I uncheck it & check it again, I got **exception:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

which is pointed to the `init()` method's last line of code `MyObject obj = new MyObject(mHandler);`

**Why I got this exception?** I don't understand, my `mHandler` is created after I called `Looper.prepare()` in `run()`.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure the error is saying you're trying to do something UI related when not on the UI thread.

Comment: THanks for the hint, but I am not able to find where am I wrong with this hint

Comment: What's HandleMessage() doing ? The error you're getting means the thread is trying to do something UI (toast, etc) but is not the UI thread. Thus the error. Google the error, the sidebar is full of similar problems, all related to doing UI work on a non-UI thread.

Comment: my handleMessage() method isn't doing anything with UI, it simply check the installed app package names

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't posted anything that you're doing inside the `handleMessage`, I'm gonna assume that you're trying to change one of the UI elements. Always use the UI thread to update the UI. It should go something like this:

```
handleMessage(Message msg) {
    ...
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable {
        ...
        // update UI here
        ...
    });
    ...
}
```

Comment: my handleMessage() method isn't doing anything with UI, it simply check the installed app package names

Comment: Are you sure none of the UI objects are touched in handleMessage()? A toast is made or a dialog is modified, perhaps? Also, could you post the code inside handleMessage()?

Answer (score 0):

just use a HandlerThread():

```
ht = new HandlerThread();
ht.start();
h = new Handler(ht.getLooper());
```